# How to choose grid from grid editor?

Tags: javascript, extjs, web

ExtJS 4.
I have grid and editor for it. Editor have listener. How to get access to grid from listener?

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 2,
    pluginId: 'cellplugin'
})],
columns: [
    {
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e) {
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    !!!NEED TO ACCESS GRID HERE, FOR EXAMPLE IN VARIABLE!!!
                    var grid = SOME?CODE?;
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    // ...
],
// ...
```

});

And I can merge editor not from this grid. So this command need to be universal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel',{
itemId : 'gridPanel',   //we need to call your grid somehow
plugins: [Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
    clicksToEdit: 2,
    pluginId: 'cellplugin'
})],
columns: [
    {
    header: 'Name',
    dataIndex: 'name',
    editor: {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        listeners: {
            specialkey: function(field, e) {
                if (e.getKey() == e.ENTER) {
                    var grid = this.up('#gridPanel'); //and access it like this
                }
            }
        }
    }},
    // ...
],
// ...
```

Comment: It could be better, if I would't add itemId in every grid.

Comment: In such case you could use xtype selector `this.up('gridpanel')`

Comment: No. grid variable is undefined, even if I use `code`this.up('#gridPanel')`code`. `code`Only Ext.getCmp()`code` works. And I don't so.

Comment: try, `field.ownerCt` and traverse upwards?

Comment: No. field doesn't have this method. It seems field goes in it's own object tree. By using superclass I went up to abstract component, but didn't see my grid or something same. If was just some types of fields.

Comment: superclass wont lead you to container. `ownerCt` will. Every field in ExtJS inherits from `Ext.Component` the `ownerCt` property (not method).

Comment: ownerCt - undefined. Also findParentByType() using grid, gridpanel and other didn't find anything.

Comment: Hmm... that would mean editor field is not actually placed into grid's container... We'd need to find some other way.